# How to monitor virtual memory usage on Opencart checkout

Tags: php, ajax, memory, memory-management, opencart

In a previous question I posted, I mentioned that we randomly get a `500 Internal Server Error` alerts on Opencart checkout. This seems to occur on AJAX calls to a backend .php/.tpl file. The temporary solution is to reprocess the ajax when the error alert triggers. For now, the solution is working as we have yet to get a `500 Internal Server Error` alert.

I am trying to look deeper into the problem. Hopefully, I can come up with a better fix.

The only lead I have is on cpanel logs. On resource monitor, the virtual memory seems to reach its limit when the error generates. On the error log, this is generaled as well:

> '*(12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp...*'

My assumption is there could be a memory issue somewhere along the pages being called on checkout.

I've created a table log on the database and written a model (PHP) that checks the memory usage each time it's called:

```
class ModelToolMem extends Model {
    public function memory_usage_logs($page_route, $page_process){
       $peak = memory_get_peak_usage();
       $peak_kb = $peak/1024;
       $peak_mb = $peak_kb/1024;
       $peak_mb = number_format($peak_mb, 2, '.', ',');
       $peak_details = "peak memory usage = $peak_mb MB";
       $sql = "INSERT INTO table_memory_log (page, process, details, date_time) VALUES ('$page_route', '$page_process', '$peak_details', NOW())";
       $this->db->query($sql);
    }
}
```

The model gets called via scripts on each page called. A sample script is as follows:

```
$this->load->model('tool/res_mon');
$this->model_tool_mem->memory_usage_logs('quickcheckout/some_page', 'some_page.php > validate');
```

As I do a test checkout, the memory allotted to the running script is recorded on the database. The biggest memory I observed on the log is 3.00 MB, which would be normal?

However, as I finished doing a test run and checked on the cpanel logs, I saw that there were instances when the virtual memory reached its limit and this appeared in the error logs:

> '(12)Cannot allocate memory...'

But when I checked on the logs in the database, I did not see any unusual increase in the memory.

What would be a better way to monitor the virtual memory usage when a PHP script is executed? Is there other PHP command aside from `memory_get_peak_usage()`?

Thanks

Comment: I failed to mention that our web host has increased virtual memory allotted to use.

Comment: I would suggest to *search and destroy* the potential memory eater! Such memory greedy thing could be a never ending loop or recursion, or too many nested loops or recursions or the combination of them - just to mention a few. In OC **normally** 64MB of RAM should be enough. It is not enough if you have more than 10-15 concurrent connections (customers viewing the site at the same moment) but (only) doubling that memory should be OK again. How many concurrent connections do you have? OC eats approx. 8-10 MB of RAM per thread. Increasing the memory limit can solve nothing but add to frustration

Comment: *Those 8-10 MB per thread were only observed on my local machine at the APACHE thread).*

Comment: Yes @shadyyx, search/destroy approach is the best way. The trick is to pin down the 'memory hungry' codes.

I've taken a look at the codes again and again and saw some unnecessary AJAX calls- that was the search part. 

I will comment out those calls- that should be the destroy part. Hopefully this should lessen the memory gobble.

Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I didn't help that much, though :-)